# In RSA, how to calculate the private exponent 'd', after choosing 'e'?

Tags: encryption, rsa

Seems there are 2 ways:

1. `d = (ϕ(n)*k + 1) / e`
   In this case, need to choose a proper integer k.
   **Question 1**: How to choose k, just try positive integers start from **1**, until found one?
2. Use `The Extended Euclidean algorithm`, make `d * e - k * ϕ(n) == 1`, where `k` can be adjusted as need.
   Seems need to add `LCM(e, ϕ(n))` to `d * e` part, if d is negative ?

**Question 2**: Are the two ways identical, if not, which one is preferred? To me, seems way `1` is easier to calculate.

**Question 3**: Will there be multiple valid `d`, since both has a variable`k`? If yes, which one to use, the smallest or any one ?

**Question 4**: If possible, can u point out relevant file/functions in the [source code](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/) of openssh.

---

### Example

```
input:
    e = 3, p1 = 11, p2 = 17,
    m = 123

encryption:
    n = 11 * 17 = 187
    c = 30

decryption:
    ϕ = 10 * 16 = 160

    3d - 160k = 1,          // e * d % ϕ(n) == 1
    d = 107, k = 2,         // can be calculated via either way,

    m = 123

public key:     n = 187, e = 3,
private key:    d = 107
```

I can calculate `d` in either way, and in both cases k = 2 is the first k met the requirement, I'm not sure is there more k that works.

Comment: Some tangentially related Q&A about negative and oversized RSA exponents: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/31795/why-can-t-the-public-key-exponent-in-rsa-be-negative and https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/29126/is-there-an-upper-bound-to-the-private-exponent-in-rsa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several valid ways to *choose* $d$ after choosing $e$ in RSA.

All must insure that $e\,d\equiv 1\bmod\lambda(n)$, where $\lambda$ is the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function). That's the mathematically necessary and sufficient condition for $d$ to allow decryption as $m\gets c^d\bmod n$ of ciphertext $c=m^e\bmod n$ in textbook RSA†. Additionally, it's customary that $0<d<n$, because that's specified in [PKCS#1](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#page=7). If $n=p\,q$ with $p$ and $q$ distinct primes as customary in RSA, then we can compute $\lambda(n)$ as $\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$, or equivalently as $(p-1)(q-1)/\gcd(p-1,q-1)$.

Instead of $e\,d\equiv 1\bmod\lambda(n)$, we *can* use $e\,d\equiv 1\bmod\varphi(n)$, where $\varphi$ is [Euler's totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). That's sufficient (though not necessary) for $d$ to allow decryption. Further, we can (and it used to be customary to) use $d=e^{-1}\bmod\varphi(n)$, which additionally implies $0<d<\varphi(n)$, and thus insures the customary $0<d<n$.

---

The question uses the later method, and asks how to *calculate* $d=e^{-1}\bmod\varphi(n)$; that is, by definition, the integer $d\in\bigl[0,\varphi(n)\bigr)$ with $\varphi(n)$ dividing $e\,d-1$.

The question's method 1 uses that there is a unique integer $k\in[0,e)$ with $e\,d=k\,\varphi(n)+1$. Thus a simple algorithm goes:

- $v=1$
- while $e$ does not divide $v$

  - $v\gets v+\varphi(n)$
- output $v/e$

Problem with this is that the loop runs $k$ times, and that can be up to nearly $e$ times and in the the order of $e/2$ times on average. For very small $e$ (including up to say $e=2^{(2^2)}+1=17$) that's entirely fine. For the common $e=2^{(2^4)}+1=65537$, that's barely tolerable. If for some reason we use a very large $e$ (e.g. 60-bit or more), that's too much work.

The question's method 2 uses the (full) [Extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). This finds $a$ and $b$ such that $a\,e+b\,\varphi(n)=1$ in a systematic way. It follows that the desired $d$ is $a\bmod\varphi(n)$. The number of steps is $\mathcal O(\log e)$ rather than $\mathcal O(e)$, which makes the method practical whenever RSA itself is.

Since we do not need $b$, we can use a simplified version of the Extended Euclidean algorithm that maintain less variables, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Modular_integers), or [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/54477/555) for a minor variant that uses only only non-negative integers. There are yet other methods that avoid Euclidean division altogether, see [this](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/972.pdf) and it's references.

---

> Are the two ways identical, if not, which one is preferred?

The methods 1 and 2 give the same result. Method 2 is preferable unless $e$ is very small. Also, method 2 detects an invalid $e$, that is one with $\gcd\bigl(e,\varphi(n)\bigr)\ne1$; when method 1 as written above loops forever (that's easily fixed by limiting to less than $e$ loops).

IMHO it's preferable to use one of the variant of method 2, *and* use that to compute $d=e^{-1}\bmod\lambda(n)$ rather than $d=e^{-1}\bmod\varphi(n)$. That's because the formual with $\lambda(n)$ yields the smallest valid non-negative $d$, which is

- mathematically pleasing
- required by some standards (e.g. [FIPS 186-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=62))
- permitted by most others

Note: the use of $\lambda(n)$ often yields a smaller $d$, which then typically yields a faster computation of $c^d\bmod n$ when that's done directly. That argument is specious though, because the gain is typically tiny, and when performance matters, implementations do not use $d$ anyway; rather, they use $d_p=e^{-1}\bmod(p-1)=d\bmod(p-1)$ and $d_q=e^{-1}\bmod(q-1)=d\bmod(q-1)$ to compute $c^{d_p}\bmod p$ and $c^{d_q}\bmod q$, then combine these per the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), and these $d_q$ and $d_q$ do not depend on how we choose $d$.

---

> Will there be multiple valid $d$, since both has a variable $k$?

There are infinitely many $d$ with $e\,d\equiv 1\bmod\varphi(n)$, but methods 1 and 2 both yield the only one $d$ in the interval $\bigl[0,\varphi(n)\bigr)$.

Note: assuming $p$ and $q$ are odd, which is necessary for security, there are at least two $d$ in $\bigl[0,\varphi(n)\bigr)$ that are valid. If $d$ is one, then $d-\varphi(n)/2$ or $d+\varphi(n)/2$ is another. Again the smallest non-negative valid $d$ is $e^{-1}\bmod\lambda(n)$.

---

In the question's artificially small (thus totally insecure) example, $e=3$, $p_1=11$ (often named $p$), $p_2=17$ (often noted $q$). $p_1$ and $p_2$ are distinct odd primes, as they should. $e=3$ is coprime with $p_1-1=10$ and $p_2-1=16$, thus $(e,p_1,p_2)$ are a valid  combination (note: since $3$ is prime, testing this reduces to checking that $3$ divides neither $10$ nor $16$). $n=p_1\,p_2=187$. $\varphi(n)=(p_1-1)(p_2-1)=160$. Computing $d=e^{-1}\bmod\varphi(n)$ by method $1$ goes:

- $3$ does not divide $v=1$, move to $v=1+160=161$
- $3$ does not divide $v=161$, move to $v=161+160=321$
- $3$ divides $v=321$, yielding $d=321/3=107$.

If we go for $d=e^{-1}\bmod\lambda(n)$: $\lambda(n)=\varphi(n)/\gcd(p_1,p_2)=80$, the same method yields $d=81/3=27$ on the second attempted division.

---

† For any plaintext $m\in[0,n)$, with the additional requirement $\gcd(m,n)=1$ when $n$ is divisible by the square of a prime. That later condition typically is forbidden in RSA. When $n$ is the product of two primes, which is customary, that would only occur if these primes are equal, or equivalently when $n$ can be factored by taking it's square root.

Comment: So, method 1 has time complexity `O(e)`, while method 2 has `O(lg(e))`. BTW, I think if we choose `e` first, then we can easily detect whether `(p1 - 1)` and `(p2 - 1)` are co-prime with `e` when choosing `p1` and `p2`, if it's not, re-choose `p1` and `p2`.

Comment: BTW, I found `λ(n) ` magical.

Comment: If $e$ is small, $k = (-\varphi(n))^{-1} \pmod e$ then $d = \frac{k\varphi(n)+1}{e}$ would be faster than large modular inversions I guess, but breaking with tradition would be unnecessary for an uncommon calculation like the final steps of key generation.